# How can I remove objects via datablocks outliner?

Tags: objects, outliner

I am searching for a method to remove corrupted or unused objects, without having to directly click on the object.

I am not sure if its an unsolved bug, but currently many of my files suffering from 2 empties, that aren't in the outliner list for "all scenes", but can be found in the "Blender file" outliner list and of course in the datablocks. Unfortunately I can not click on the objects in the Blender file list, so deleting there isn't possible.

I know these empties were used as custom bone shapes in an armature. This armature doesn't exist anymore, so I guess both empties are trapped in my file. They are not linked.

How can I safely remove objects from the datablocks /the file, even if I don't know where they are?

Comment: Can you post the blend file?

Answer (score 1):

#### [Edit 2 Jan, 2016]

You can delete datablocks of any type by way of the outliner window. Find the object, select it in the outliner, right-click on the item, and select "delete" from the context menu.

#### [Original answer]

But you wrote in your question that many of your files are

> "suffering from 2 empties".

Your problem might be that these can't be deleted as empties, because they are phantom bones and not empties at all. You will probably find the objects you want to delete if you look under the armatures in your file. You don't need to be in datablock view to do this. If you select the armatures in the "all scenes" view of the outliner one by one, I expect you will find which armature contains the bones (or that the two bones may not be in the same armature. In either case, in object mode in the 3D viewport, looking under armatures, I expect you will be able to delete the phantom bones.

But, it might want to be careful about deleting the bones, because it is possible to delete a bone from the middle of a chain, so that there may be other bones connected as children of the phantom bone which will be deleted if you delete the phantom bone.

Comment: I will look into that, but in general: Is there no other way to delete such objects? Like "go out of my file, I dont care where you are or what you are good for". If they were really left in an armature, then it should just remove the bone shape in this case, because the target is deleted. So thats not a drama.

Comment: @Wäsch, there may well be other ways to delete objects similar to the ones you've been plagued with, than the method I describe. I just don't happen to know them. With armature bones, though, perhaps more than with other sub-object types, there may be the addtiional problem that in edit mode, one can delete a bone without affecting the children or the parents, and this might generally not be a good thing to allow. Todds suggestion to post your blend file (to [Blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), or a similar site would be helpful to those who would like to help.